# Lua os.execute empty terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, lua, love2d

I have a program that requires me to call os.execute to run an external program, however, when I do this, the program runs with an empty terminal sitting open in the background, which is quite a pain. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows, you can use the [winapi](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/api.html#shell_exec) library, specifically `winapi.execute()` which will run an application without popping up a terminal window.

Comment: And on linux? (I tend to make this as multiplatform as possible)

Comment: Have you tried :-) ? Ok, executing a command by a system shell does not open a window on Linux.